# in Android, is there any way of use classes to format a group´of views?

Tags: java, android, css, class

I'm beginning in Android development and I got very familiar with the XML notation, since it's pretty similar to HTML. 
By the XML we can set ID's to the views for later managing it with Java, as like we do with HTML and JS. 
My point is: Can I define classes or something like that to set similiar attributes to a group of views?
Sorry if I was unclear or anything, and thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

You can define `styles` and use those across widgets.

Here are the official docs for it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using styles.
in res/values/ create a file named styles.xml [Auto generated in Android Studio]

You can define new style using the style tag :

```
<style name="styleName"></style>
```

You can also modify an already present style by using :

```
<style name="styleName2" parent="alreadyExistingStyle"></style>
```

Than you use it in xml and as well as Java.
In xml :

```
style="@style/styleName"
```

In Java :

```
R.style.styleName
```

Example :

Button Style :

```
<style name="AppButtonLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/hw_btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Than use it in xml :

```
<Button
    style="@style/AppButtonLight"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnDownload"
    android:id="@+id/btnDownload" />
```

Hope I was able to help you.